# "failed to synthesize type class instance" in rewrite subproof

Tags: typeclass, lean

The code below fails verification with **"failed to synthesize type class instance for ... `⊢ has_pow R R`"**.

This seems weird because I used the same operator (`^`) on the same types in the enclosing scope, and there was no problem! The second theorem, with the same signature, type-checks fine.

**Why does it only fail inside the rewrite? How can I fix it without changing the theorem's type signature?**

```
import algebra.group_power

theorem pow_eq_zero_1 {R : Type} [domain R] {r : R} {n : ℕ} : r ^ (n + 1) = 0 → r = 0
:= begin
  rw (show r ^ (n + 1) = r ^ n * r,
      by { have rn := λ x : R, r ^ x,
           sorry, }),
  sorry,
end

theorem pow_eq_zero_2  {R : Type} [domain R] {r : R} {n : ℕ} : r ^ (n + 1) = 0 → r = 0
:= pow_eq_zero  -- it's in mathlib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because you tried to use `r^x` with `x : R`, but you'd need `x : ℕ` for it to work.